# {% Exit 404 %} doesn't work right with routes

Tags: craft3, routing, 404

The `{% exit 404 %}` doesn't work right on routed templates.

It's fine on pages that aren't affected by routes. Mysite.com/asdfasdf shows me the proper 404 page.

I've got some routes configured like this:

```
URL: projects/type/*
Template: _projects/category.twig

URL: projects/*
Template: _projects/entry.twig
```

In the top of entry.twig, I've got code that says:

```
{% set entrySlug = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug(entrySlug).one() %}

{% if entry is not defined or entry is null %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{# regular page template below here #}
```

mysite.com/projects/WorkingProject - this works right.
mysite.com/projects/BrokenProjectLink - gives me a 500 error.

When I turn on dev mode, the Yii debugger gives me a 404 ( HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException ), which is the right thing. But turning devmode off, I don't get the 404 page, I get my 500 Internal Server Error page instead.

Again, 404s for pages that don't have any routing work fine. It's just things that are getting routed, and using the `{% exit 404 %}` code.

This all worked in v3.3.20 and earlier, but it doesn't seem to work the same in Craft 3.4.0.2.

Comment: Answered below, but I'm compelled to ask why the native Entry/Category routing doesn't suffice? If you've set up your Sections and Category Groups to use the native Element URI/routing system, you wouldn't need to perform manual lookups at all!

Comment: Yeah, it's because the categories and individual entries live in the same parent segment. I want everything that's /projects/type/ to use category, and /projects/<project name> to go to the actual project pages. (and I can't change that) With native routing, the /projects/type/non-existent-category, it tries to load the entry template, and gives the wrong sort of 404.

Comment: This sounds like unusual behavior… Element templates should only be loaded if their complete URI matches the request (see the `elements_sites` table). Craft won't make any inference about the path down to your Entry when a specific one isn't found—it'll just continue on and look up a user-defined route (i.e. via the CP or `routes.php`).

Answer (score 2):

When a route is accessed, `entry` isn't automatically defined.

The actual value for `*` is available in the `any` variable in your template—see this example:

```
Route: projects/type/(*)
Template: _test
```

```
{# templates/_test.twig #}
Substituted route param: {{ any }}
```

Do note that `entry` is not automatically set by Craft for any custom routes! It's your responsibility to take the incoming value (in your case, `any`) and look up the Entry, within the template, or bail if nothing is found:

```
{# We can totally skip the test for `any`, because this template is only loaded when there's a non-zero-length value in the route: #}
{% set entry = craft.entries({ title: any }).one() %}

{% if not entry %}
  {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{# At this point, you've set `entry`, and can use it however you like! #}
{{ entry.myFieldHandle }}
```

> I'd recommend reviewing the requirements for your route, and consider using a more specific token in your route (i.e. `(slug)`), and matching based on a more stable value—titles can change, but IDs should stick around, and slugs are less prone to editing!

Comment: I'm sure you're right about the route. I'll take 'em all out, see how it works, and re-do them. . Added some more code to my original Q. I actually do have a chunk of code that gets an entry from the URL. For client reasons, I've got some subpages on projects that do some template magic based on the url, e.g. ```/project/this-old-house``` and ```/projects/this-old-house/thumbnails```.